# Is there a way to make a custom transition between textures in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I am trying to make a model viewer in three.js using opengl.
And one of the features that I want to make is to change textures during runtime.
I already did it. But it seems a little brutal to me, I wanted something more cool. Like this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BGkAht67WyE&list=PL4eqhhbLRZhO4NUyauiH7RAfs1sYUe_7_&index=6).
Of course I know it's an advanced stuff, but I didn't find any examples about it.
Some tips?

Comment: I think you would need a custom ShaderMaterial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to lerp (linearly interpolate) between the two textures. Your fragment shader needs to hold both textures and then trigger lerping once you load the second texture, the one that you want to change to. Than use operation like `col = fromTex.rgb * (1.0-t) + toTex.rgb * t` and change the blending/lerping coefficient `t` throughout the time until you completely blend into the second texture. `t` can be sent as a uniform that would be slowly changing from the `0.0->1.0` over the time.

Comment: That's it! Worked well.

Comment: Or you could use the `mix` function in the fragment shader. Even simpler.